# ImportError: cannot import name 'MovieGroupProcess' from gsdmm

Tags: python, git, path, python-import

I'm having some import issues using a Python module I cloned from GitHub.

My project structure looks like such

```
   -Jupyter_notebook.ipynb

   -gsdmm/
```

The gsdmm/ folder was cloned into the same directory as the notebook from [GitHub here](https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm) using

```
git clone https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm.git
```

Now my import error happens anytime I try to import the 'MovieGroupProcess' class from the module as shown in the readme. I'm running it from a Jupyter notebook but same issue exists in Python script

```
from gsdmm import MovieGroupProcess
```

where I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MovieGroupProcess' from 'gsdmm' ([current_directory]\gsdmm\__init__.py)
```

I'm not sure if something was messed up with my paths or needs to be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your project structure

```
.
├── gsdmm
│   ├── gsdmm
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mgp.py
│   └── test
└── Jupyter_notebook.ipynb
```

Then trying to import `gssdmm` from your notebook `Jupyter_notebook` won't work as there is not `__init__.py` file inside the first `gsdmm` directory.

But if you change the project structure to

```
.
└── gsdmm
    ├── gsdmm
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mgp.py
    ├── test
    └── Jupyter_notebook.ipynb
```

Now when you import `gsdmm` python can find the `__init__.py` file and can import the module successfully.